# What is this insect? Possible assassin bug? or kissing bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I saw this bug (around 2 cm) in the front of the balcony door inside the room.

[image][image]

I googled and found two same insects- *Assassin* bug and *Kissing* bug. Could they hide their eggs inside the room? Should I be worried?
I live in Vienna, Austria

Thanks in advance

Update: I found this bug here https://www.massaudubon.org/learn/nature-wildlife/insects-arachnids/western-conifer-seed-bugs
The bug that I saw looks like a Western Conifer Seed Bugs! Do you agree?

Comment: I found this bug here https://www.massaudubon.org/learn/nature-wildlife/insects-arachnids/western-conifer-seed-bugs

Comment: Kissing bug that carries Chagas disease is in the Americas.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it does seem to be a Western Conifer Seed Bug (Leptoglossus occidentalis). Not a hazard to people.

Photos from Italian language wikipedia.

[image]
[image]

This ref below suggests it may be looking for somewhere indoors to wait out the winter. It lays eggs on conifer leaves.

http://www.zin.ru/animalia/coleoptera/pdf/steyrer_perny_2008_new_insect_species_in_austria.pdf

"Two New Insect Species in Austria: One Established, the Other One Not (Yet)" by
Gottfried Steyrer and Berhard Perny,
Forstschutz Aktuell, num 44, 2008

Comment: Thank so much for your help. Now I can calm myself down. It sounds harmless. Blaming myself for killing a harmless creature.